# Prints text only at the end of a while loop

Tags: c, printf

I wanted to print every time the loop runs to print a text, but my program only print's it when the loop runs the last time.
My Code:

```
while (shots>i){
  printf ("%s", message);
  i++;
  sleep(1);
}
```

At the end I just get all the outputs at one moment .

Comment: Output buffering. Try: printf("%s\n", ..) or fflush(stdout).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf` to flush your output from buffer to `stdout`.

The output would not go to `stdout` before buffer being full or special character like '\n' comes, you need to do it manually(by call `fflush`).

Answer (score 3):

Try using [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush). This wil clear the stdout buffer before sleep executes. So your new code block will look like this:

```
while (shots>i){
  printf ("%s", message);
  fflush(stdout);
  i++;
  sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf` uses a buffer. So only gets printed when either the buffer is full or that the buffer is flushed.